# Infinite loop in method with catch statement and crashes

Tags: java, try-catch

I am writing a program to determine gas mileage for a trip. However, I want to ensure the user does not enter a String or a Char at the prompt and ensure the user enters a Double. I set a try/catch, as I had in other programs with no issues, but this one is giving me issues. But the program keeps looping back through the method and then crashes. I have tried putting it in a while loop and tried putting each input in a separate try-catch with no luck.

```
private static double[] gas(){
    double gasCost[] = new double[3];
    System.out.println("********************************************************");
    System.out.print("What is the current price of gas per gallon, ie...2.84: $");
    try{
        gasCost[0] = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("On average, how many miles to the gallon does your vehicle get, ie...22.5: ");
        gasCost[1] = input.nextDouble();
        gasCost[2] = gasCost[0] / gasCost[1];             
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("\nERROR!! Invalid input, please try again!\n");
        gas();
    }
    return gasCost;
}
```

Comment: make sure you call input.nextLine() after every call to input.nextDouble() to clear the end of line character the user enters after typing their double value.

Comment: Calling this method recursively the way you do is a Very Bad Idea™. Try to think through on paper what exactly happens when an exception is thrown and you'll immediately see why. (Or try it out with a debugger.)

Comment: When `nextDouble()` throws an `InputMismatchException`, it doesn't actually advance past the token. You have to call `next()` to skip the invalid input.

Comment: use this method to help you grab doubles from the user -> public static double getDoubleFromUserWithPrompt(Scanner input, String prompt)
 {
  double val = Double.NaN;
  boolean validDouble = false;
  String userInput = "";
  while(!validDouble)
  {
   System.out.println(prompt);
   try
   {
    userInput = input.nextLine();
    val = Double.parseDouble(userInput);
    validDouble = true;
   }catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Invalid Double entered : " + userInput);
    System.out.println("Try Again...");
   }
  }
  
  return val;
 }

Comment: then call it in your current method like so -> gasCost[0] = getDoubleFromUserWithPrompt(input, "What is the current price of gas per gallon, ie...2.84: $");

Comment: @Michael Not recursion in general, but recursion **as used in this code snippet**. Just imagine what happens if the first input fails, and `gas()` is called again. Instead of returning the result of the second, successful input, the outermost invocation of `gas()` will return the partially filled `double[]` array of the failed first. (If it said `return gas();`, the result would of course be correct.)

Comment: @Michael That's why I said "the way you do it". Otherwise recursion is a perfectly fine tool, I've had lots of fun with it over the years. :)

Comment: @biziclop Then your wording was very strange. You effectively tried to state "that bug is a bad idea". "Your code contains a bug" might have been more clear. Anyway, gonna delete my comments 'cause this isn't constructive.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your code to this for debugging purposes and you'll see exactly why it keeps failing:

```
try{
    //...         
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println(e.toString()); // < added this
    System.out.println("\nERROR!! Invalid input, please try again!\n");
    gas();
}
```

You, at least, need to call `input.nextLine()` after each call to `nextDouble` to consume the line.

---

Complete side note, don't use arrays for this purpose. It's difficult to see what index relates to what value. Define a class and return that.

```
class Gas {
    private final double cost;
    private final double mileage;

    Gas(double cost, double mileage) {
        this.cost = cost;
        this.mileage = mileage;
    }

    double getEfficiency() {
        return cost / mileage; // check for divide by zero too
    }

    //getters for the other fields (maybe)
}
```

Your gas method:

```
private static Gas gas(){
    //...

    return new Gas(cost, mileage);
}
```